# How to test application after letting it run in background for X amount of hours?

Tags: android, testing

I am facing bugs in my application that only show up after the application has been running in the background for many hours. Some times "many hours" are 24 or 36. It is very difficult to try to fix those bugs if I have to wait that long. What are my options? Thank you.

Comment: Dont include tag name in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of one way which unfortunately is dependent on Android version and provider ROM.

```
Settings->Developer Options->Do not keep activities.
```

Set this, then put your app in the background.  Your activity will be destroyed immediately.  Then resume your app.  The bugs will show.

You might also want to review how and when to save instance state between onPause() and onResume()

Comment: Is this not available on on all? Do you know which version this is available?

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is what I was looking for.

Comment: you're welcome.  To answer your question, I don't know which versions since I am always fiddling with custom ROMs and lose track :)  Current ROM is a custom Jelly Bean 4.1.1 derived from stock running on Galaxy S3 which does have the full set of developer options.

Comment: Yep, got my hands on Galaxy S2

Answer (score 0):

a likely problem is that some of your variables are cleared, like global variables,due to memory management and when your application comes back through the lifecycle after `onResume()` it gets null exceptions.

What you can try to do is persist some of those variables in sharedpreferences during `onPause()` or do null checks in onResume, onStart and onCreate

Comment: That is good information but it doesn't help me to test my application. I need to reproduce those bugs, and they occur after long time of letting the application run in the background. What can I do to make it so that the application has run in the background for long time without me actually having to wait that long myself.

Comment: you can try using a crash/error reporting service like ACRA which will tell you what the errors are no matter when they happen, whether you are debugging or not. the question you are asking is more so reactionary and isn't the absolute way to approach fixing this problem.

Comment: "some of your variables are cleared". I'm confused.  Android does not clear your variables unless they go out of scope or it kills them all by destroying your activity so, I guess your activity is being destroyed.  To simulate, go to Settings->Developers Options->Don't keep activities (or something like that don't have my phone at the moment)  Imagine if it cleared variables in an arbitrary way.  There would not be a single stable app on the entire platform.

Comment: @Simon activities can access global variables or variables stored in other activities. So it makes perfect sense. Checking for null before accessing a variable helps ensure stability.

Comment: No it doesn't.  A global always exists as long as your app (the process exists) - always.  Activities cannot access variables in another activity without shenanigans and, when they do and the activity is destroyed, you leak.  The activity is part of the UI and should be treated as such.  I can assure you that GCing an in scope variable would be a serious bug in Android.

Comment: Imagine the GC did free up in scope objects. In scope means that something has a reference to it. When it does, the object no longer exists and any references (variables) to it are no longer valid.  myVariable == null would fail since it requires a valid reference and null is a reference.  Null only has meaning when associated with a valid reference . It's the default value for all reference types.  Imagine the GC does free in scope objects. The memory used by the object is returned to the heap. You now have no clue what is in that memory.

Comment: @Simon good to know, yet I've had variables come back null after the app having been in the background for an indeterminate amount of time, despite this lesson in semantics my suggestions will lead to fixing this problem

Comment: That's because the activity was destroyed and the vars were reinitialised when the activity was created.   Nothing to do with GC other than freeing up the activity resources when it was destroyed.  The reason for caring about this is that I've seen several responses saying that Android GCs global vars or some such and that is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) if you need to run a process in Background for long